# vector of vectors of multiple objects and primitive types in C++ and OpenCV

Tags: c++, object, opencv, vector, primitive-types

I'm writing a program using c++ and opencv lib in which I need to store data in one place for temporary convenience(so that i can access info without moving too much) and  not write in a file.

So I want to create a vector of vectors of multiple objects(like 2 cv::Point3f objects) and atom data types(int, int, float, Boolean)

Is this possible to create a vector of vectors of these objects and primitive types? If yes how can I do that? If no what other options are there?

Comment: You mean like `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point3f, cv::Point3f>>>` or `std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, float, Boolean>>>`? Note that typedefs and `auto` work well with those, and that `Boolean` isn't a primitive type in C++ (it's `bool`).

Comment: Sorry for not understanding. I want all objects and primitives as single vector of vectors. Didn't you just created two separate vectors?

Comment: Those are two examples of how you could incorporate two or more separate variables in one. The first creates a pair (2) of which the first can be accessed with `first()` and the second with `second()`. The second can have something like 20 elements IIRC, accessed with `get<N>`. It's like an array where you specify what type each element is, not just have one. I'm sure those should easily work themselves in if they're what you're after.

Comment: Oh, never mind the max of 20 elements. I recalled how boost would have a macro for each layer, but now we have variadic templates, so there's only need for one to handle any number of elements. I'm also not the person to get into about tuples; I've never actually gotten around to using one yet. Note that you need C++11 for `tsd::tuple` though. `boost::tuple` works in C++03, but that's where the size restriction is.

Comment: I'm having difficulties figuring out how to access data using boost::tuple. My code is: `std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<CvPoint3d32f, int, int, float, Boolean>>> test12;
    test12[0] = make_tuple(cvPoint3d32f(2.0,3.0,1.2), 5, 6.0, true);` How do i access each element of Point3d32f or element int?

Comment: Like I said, I've never used them, but something like `get<N>()` should return element N.

Comment: I've created and initialized the vector of tupple. The code is: `std::vector < boost::tuple <CvPoint3D32f, int, int, float, bool> > test12;
    test12[0] = boost::make_tuple(cvPoint3D32f(2.0,3.0,1.2), 5, 1, 6.0, true);
    std::cout << boost::get<0>(test12).x << std::endl;
    ` But getting error sayin' no matching function get(). Can anyone kindly help me solve this error? My boost version 1.33.1 on debian etch linux.

Comment: Sorry new to this forum. accidentally clicked chat. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Those who are interested:

```c
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>

int main()
{

    std::vector < boost::tuple <CvPoint3D32f, CvPoint3D32f, int, int, float, bool> > test12;

    test12.push_back(boost::make_tuple(cvPoint3D32f(2.0, 3.0, 1.2), cvPoint3D32f(2.5, 7.0, 5.2), 5, 1, 6.0, true));

    std::cout << boost::get<0>(test12[0]).z << std::endl;

    return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Is this possible to create a vector of vectors of these objects and primitive types? If yes how can I do that?**

Yes it is possible to have have vector of vectors, For ex:

```
  // Vector length of 3 initialized to 0
   vector<int> myMatrix(3,0);

   // Vector length of 4 initialized to hold another
   // vector myMatrix which has been initialized to 0
   vector< vector<int> > myMatrix2(4, myMatrix);

   // Vector of length 5 containing two dimensional vectors
   vector< vector< vector<int> > > myMatrix3(5, myMatrix2);
```

Comment: I think the `of multiple objects` part implies that `int` become `std::tuple` in most cases.

Comment: @chris: I have no idea.If this is not what the OP needs I will delete it soon.